# OPENDATASOURCE and MS Access syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ms-access

Attempting to use OPENDATASOURCE with an Access file and can't seem to get the syntax right. I am trying to open the APPT table in the database listed in the below path.

```
select * from OPENDATASOURCE ('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Data Source=C:\Users\anthony.parker\Downloads\Conversion Database.mdb').APPT
```

This doesn't work; what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `'Data Source="...."'` instead? Note the `"`-quotes inside there.

Comment: When placing the qoutes in there, it errors out

Comment: The issue could be with the space in the filename. Can you change the file name to remove the space? Conversion Database.mdb to ConversionDatabase.mdb?

Comment: Changed the code to:  select * from OPENDATASOURCE ('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Data Source=C:\Users\anthony.parker\Downloads\ConversionDatabase.mdb').APPT  ,

Now it says invalid object, when the table APPT is there

Comment: Does it have to be `OPENDATASOURCE`? I would generally use `OPENROWSET` with MS Access, it seems to be easier.